# Cannot Redeclare Class Error Following Compliation

Tags: magento-enterprise, compiler

## Problem

Following compilation, I get the error `Cannot redeclare class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`when accessing the admin panel.  Per [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5678/code-compilation-error-cannot-redeclare-class), I attempted to clear the cache by deleting the cached folders (currently just using Magento's file-based caching to isolate the problem) and disabled all third-party modules to make sure that those weren't the problem.

At first I thought that for some reason the core files were getting loaded in addition to the compiled ones, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

To try to isolate the issue, I added the following code to `index.php` file (root) and then ran a grep on the `get_included_files()` files for `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` -- it appears only in `__adminhtml.php` (though the file in which the class may be redeclared may not be included in the `get_included_files()` output because this is where it is choking.

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
    var_dump(get_included_files());
}
```

The resulting error:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 64
    [message] => Cannot redeclare class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
    [file] => /Users/pbirnie/sites/city-gear/includes/src/__adminhtml.php
    [line] => 2065
)
```

I also grepped for the class declaration and only see it in 5 files -- `__adminhtml.php` seems to be the only one that is actually loading...

```
pbirnie:src pbirnie$ find . -name "*.php" | xargs -n 20 grep 'class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product '
./__adminhtml.php:class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract
./__catalog.php:class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract
./__checkout.php:class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract
./__cms.php:class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract
./Mage_Catalog_Model_Product.php:class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract
```

I'm currently running Magento Enterprise 1.13.1 if that is of consequence; I do not have APC or Memcached running..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a detailed answer, but in case someone else runs into this issue on EE 1.13.1, upgrading to 1.14.0.1 resolved the issue.

### UPDATE

This may have been because the existing `stat` directory inside of the includes folder was removed - I still had the same issue on the staging environment after upgrading.  Removing the `stat` directory took care of it.

### Admin Controller Override Issue (3/2017)

I recently helped someone else with this and we ran across another possibility.  In this particular case, a third-party extension was attempting to override an admin controller.  The code was as follows:

`require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml') . DS . 'Catalog' . DS . "ProductController.php");`

This works fine until the code is compiled as it will still reference the original file (thus causing a class redeclaration error).

Changing the above code to

`require_once "Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php";` will reference the file in the compilation directory and thereby only included once.